# Why my Genymotion emulator lost after I install new version of Android studio? How to solve it?

Tags: android

I'm using Genymotion emulator. Then when I update Android Studio to version 2.1, a minute  ago, the icon genymotion lost. I'm thingking that it was already deleted. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

Go to **Preferences / Plugins** and click “Browse Repositories”, then search for **Genymotion**. Right click and choose “Download and Install”. Restart Android Studio and you should see a new icon in your IDE. Click the icon and it will bring up Preferences, and choose the path to the Genymotion application.

also refer [this](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2013/11/22/android-studio-plus-genymotion-emulator/)